# How insert data to parent and child tables

Tags: postgresql

I working with postgeSQL and I have such a question.

I have two tables witch looks like this:

Parent:

```
CREATE TABLE public.parent
(
    parent_id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    child_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT parent_pkey PRIMARY KEY (parent_id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_child UNIQUE (child_id)
,
    CONSTRAINT child_fkey FOREIGN KEY (child_id)
        REFERENCES public.child (child) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Child:

```
CREATE TABLE public.child
(
    child bigint NOT NULL,
    money double precision NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT child_pkey PRIMARY KEY (child)
)
```

So, I wanna insert data in parent table and in the same time in child table. How it can be done in one query? Is it possible?

Comment: What you call the child is actually the parent table, and what you call the parent is actually the child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=40d59ab2246e3dd70316044353098b9a)

Using CTE (`WITH` clause) allows to do a double insert:

```
WITH insert_child AS (
    INSERT INTO child VALUES
    (42, 5.23)
    RETURNING child
)
INSERT INTO parent
SELECT 
    /* parent data */
    child
FROM insert_child;
```

A query with a CTE executes the CTE query independently and before the "main" query. The result of the CTE can be used further. The CTE `INSERT` statement returns the inserted child id with the `RETURNING` clause. This is used by the following query.

[Further reading, Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

Comment: How can you make this work if you have a foreign key constraint on the child table's ID?

Comment: @user2340939 The tables are named opposite according to normal conventions!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to complete this requirement is to use CTE, like below:

```
with tmp1 as (
 insert into child values(1001,27500.0) returning child
 )
insert into parent select 101,'Bob','Bob@gmail.com',tmp1.child from tmp1;
INSERT 0 1

select * from child;
 child | money 
-------+-------
  1001 | 27500

select * from parent;
 parent_id | name |     email     | child_id 
-----------+------+---------------+----------
       101 | Bob  | Bob@gmail.com |     1001
```

or you can write a trigger.